# Is an Averaged neural network (avNNet) the average from all iterations?

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret, nnet

I have fitted an Averaged neural network in R with Caret. See code below. Does the term Averaged mean that the average is based on the outcomes of 1000 neural networks? (since there are 1000 iterations in this case)

Thanks.

```
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
data(solubility)

### Create a control funciton that will be used across models. We
### create the fold assignments explictily instead of relying on the
### random number seed being set to identical values.

library(caret)
set.seed(100)
indx <- createFolds(solTrainY, returnTrain = TRUE)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", index = indx)

################################################################################
### Section 7.1 Neural Networks

### Optional: parallel processing can be used via the 'do' packages,
### such as doMC, doMPI etc. We used doMC (not on Windows) to speed
### up the computations.

### WARNING: Be aware of how much memory is needed to parallel
### process. It can very quickly overwhelm the availible hardware. We
### estimate the memory usuage (VSIZE = total memory size) to be 
### 2677M/core.

library(doMC)
registerDoMC(10)


library(caret)

nnetGrid <- expand.grid(decay = c(0, 0.01, .1), 
                        size = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13), 
                        bag = FALSE)

set.seed(100)
nnetTune <- train(x = solTrainXtrans, y = solTrainY,
                  method = "avNNet",
                  tuneGrid = nnetGrid,
                  trControl = ctrl,
                  preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                  linout = TRUE,
                  trace = FALSE,
                  MaxNWts = 13 * (ncol(solTrainXtrans) + 1) + 13 + 1,
                  maxit = 1000,
                  allowParallel = FALSE)
nnetTune

plot(nnetTune)

testResults <- data.frame(obs = solTestY,
                          NNet = predict(nnetTune, solTestXtrans))

################################################################################
```

See also:

https://scientistcafe.com/post/nnet.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`avNNet` is a model where the same neural network model is fit using different random number seeds. All the resulting models are used for prediction. For regression, the output from each network are averaged. For classification, the model scores are first averaged, then translated to predicted classes. [Source](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/avNNet).

The number of models fit is controlled by the argument `repeats` which is passed down to the model in `caret` via `...`

`repeats - the number of neural networks with different random number seeds`. At default this is set to `5`. So five models will be averaged. In [caret's definition of the model](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/RegressionTests/Code/avNNet.R) I do not see this changing.

If the `bag` argument is set to `TRUE` model fitting and aggregation is performed by [bootstrap aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating), which in my opinion is almost guaranteed to provide better predictive performance if the number of models is high enough.

Comment: @ missuse thanks! Since "All the resulting models are used for prediction" is the underlying number of models 5 * 1000 = 5000? I will add bootstrap aggregation.

Comment: The number of models is 5, if `repeats = 5`. `maxit = 1000` is just the number of weight updates. during building one model.

Comment: @ missuse do I understand correct that there are 5 models with 1000 weight updates each and x random number seeds?

Comment: Yes, each nnet starts with random initialized weights (most of the time) and then via consecutive updates (back propagation) these weights are trained. Here 1000 is the maximum number of iterations or weight updates for one model - model fitting can stop earlier based on [`abstol` and `reltol` arguments](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nnet/versions/7.3-0/topics/nnet). Anyway 1000 updates seems excessive and 5 models seems low, I would go with 200 + models with 100 - 200 updates using `bagging` with this function.

Comment: I am not sure what would be the point of not using bagging  since most of the time these nnets would arrive to a very similar solution. Also check out [keras](https://keras.rstudio.com/) which allows usage of many more architectures and much more sophisticated algorithms.

Comment: @ missuse. Thanks! I will try these settings and dive deeper into keras. Final question. Currently the MaxNWts = 13 * (ncol(solTrainXtrans) + 1) + 13 + 1. Is it optimal to replace the 13 in this formula by the maximum of size = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13)? (should I change this value every time I change the maximum value of size)

Comment: To be honest Marcel I have no idea.

Comment: @ missuse One more question if I may. Currently the optimal settings from tuning are used if I do: predict(nnetTune, solTestXtrans). Is it possible to use other settings than the optimal settings? For example with decay = 0.01 while decay = 0.10 is the optimal setting within nnetTune? Thanks!

Comment: I trust it is not possible when using `caret::train` since it would require the train object to hold all tested models which in some cases consumes a lot of memory.